# Это чтобы волосы не выпадали

Tags: синтаксис

Если я правильно понимаю, *чтобы волосы не выпадали* — придаточное цели, верно? А где здесь главное предложение?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придаточное предложение вида "это чтобы...." имеет значение цели, но при этом часто **ведет себя как самостоятельная синтаксическая единица,** например:

(1) Главное — **это чтобы** запомнилось (входит в составе **простого предложения**: Главное - это запомнить).

(2) Уверяют, что документы потеряли ― **это чтобы** сразу обратно не выслали (СПП состоит из трех предложений,  объединенных в два блока,  между блоками ставится тире).

(3) Gross- Mutter имеет пять пар туфлей, все они стоят у порогов, в одних она ходит по двору, в других по коровнику, в третьих по кухне, в четвёртых по столовой, в пятых по гостиной, ― **это чтобы** соблюсти чистоту. [Б. А. Пильняк. Три брата (1923-1928)]  Предложение "**это чтобы**..." в составе **сложного синтаксического целого** обознчает общую цель.

(4) А роза ― это с его родины. Это **чтобы** надолго дом не покидать. Как только роза высохла совсем, листья выпали ― пора, значит, домой (Денис Гуцко). Оформлено как **самостоятельное предложение по принципу парцелляции**,  местоимение "это" обозначает информацию из предыдущей части текста.

(5) Если я правильно понимаю, **это чтобы** волосы не выпадали. Или: **Это чтобы** волосы не выпадали.

Здесь также **парцелляция**, то есть "это" замещает сказанное ранее. Здесь предложение "это чтобы..." имеет более высокий статус и содержит больше информации, чем простое придаточное предложение цели. Его смысл: **это делается для того, чтобы...**

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, это вторая часть парцеллированной конструкции или реплика в диалоге, то есть неполное предложение с пропуском главного. Если бы Вы дали полный текст или его часть с этой конструкцией , мы бы ответили, как разбирать, а так непонятно, что это.

Answer (score 1):

В части первой - согласна с Людмилой:

> Скорее всего, это вторая часть парцеллированной конструкции или
> реплика в диалоге, то есть неполное предложение с пропуском главного.

И не согласна во второй - что необходим контекст.

Думаю, он легко реконструируется.

"А это что за бальзам?" - "Это чтобы волосы не выпадали".

"Это чтобы" - связка перед сказуемым. Запятой не разделяется.

Нашла пример (и разбор с пояснениями) с

[***ВСЁ РАВНО(,) КАК / ЧТО,** связка и союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_807).

Тот же случай.

Вот пример из довольно длинного текста:

> Я поблагодарил его, сел и сказал, что написать рассказ – это всё равно
> что прожить год жизни.

"У меня шампунь-кондиционер. Это чтобы волосы не выпадали".

В общем, разбирайте синтаксис предложения, не обращая внимания на "это". Оно не несёт смысловой нагрузки, только даёт живую интонацию.